# Ordered Dictionary in JSON

Tags: json, swift

There are 3 string variables

```
public var userLoginId : String?
public var searchString : String?
public var tableName : String?
```

I have a dictionary:

```
let dict = ["userLoginId" : userLoginId, "searchString" : searchString,"tableName" : tableName]
```

Now I serialize it by JSON:

```
let data =  try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options :[])
let jsonstring = String(data:data, encoding:.utf8)!
```

In `jsonstring`, every time I get an unordered JSON like below:

```
"{\"tableName\":\"null\",\"userLoginId\":\"Dilip\",\"searchString\":\"Tata\"}"
```

How can I get in the same format in which I assigned value to dictionary?

Comment: `Dictionary` doesn't have any order.

Comment: I know that dictionary doesn't have any order but First think is, i need JSON in the same order in which i put data into dictionary. Second is, To generate JSON, Dictionary is best solution, but i am new to IOS, thats why i am facing problems

Comment: @Nirav D, ordering is useful when JSON data is serialized and deserialized into a dictionary. Since the dictionary has no order, then you might end up writing a lot of different JSON strings even when coming from the same dict. Is there some way to deserialize JSON without using a Dict?

Comment: @Efren i'm afraid but but there is no other way also if you look at below [Alexander answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42292042/6433023), he is already mentioned that **Swift's Dictionary not have ordering, but neither do JSON dictionaries, as per the standard**

Comment: @DilipJangid I could suggest for this simple dictionary to convert it to array of dictionaries (to add the order), convert the result to json and remove extra brackets from the json. At least it seems to be better then fully manual serialization

Answer (score 13):

`Dictionaries` are **unordered**

## But !

Since **`JSON`** is a `String` you **can** have an ordered `JSON`.
You can use **[this library](https://github.com/mikezs/Tisander)** to parse the JSON in the original order. The usage is simple:

```
try JSON.parse(string: jsonString)
```

---

#### Sorted Dictionary

From **iOS 11** and **macOS 10.13** there is a new option for `JSONSerialization` for sorting keys that you can use:

```
JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: [.sortedKeys])
```

Comment: .sortedKeys will just put the keys in alphabetical order, it won't respect the order of the original json keys

Answer (score 2):

Not only does Swift's `Dictionary` not have ordering, but neither do JSON dictionaries, as per the standard. The best you could probably do is store the keys, in correct order, in an array. Instead of iterating the dictionary, you instead iterate the ordered array of keys, and then fetch from the dictionary with those keys.

To avoid repeating the keys manually, you can express your dictionary as an array of `(Key, Value)` tuples, like so:

```
let keyValuePairs = [
    ("userLoginId", userLoginId),
    ("searchString", searchString),
    ("tableName", tableName)
]


let dict = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: keyValuePairs)
let orderedKeys = keyValuePairs.map { $0.0 }
```

Now you can use the `orderedKeys` in your Swift code, or store them in JSON alongside the `dict`:

```
print("Example usage:")
for key in orderedKeys {
    let value = dict[key]!
    
    print("\(key): \(value)")
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a link to the standard where JSON dictionaries not being ordered is mentioned?

Comment: @algrid Search `unordered` on both https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types,_syntax_and_example or https://www.json.org/

Comment: @Alexander Can you give me example how to store them in JSON alongside the dict?

Comment: @Praveen-K Wrap the original dict and the array of its ordered keys into a parent dict

Answer (score 2):

I know this was asked a year ago. But I recently ran into this issue while writing unit tests. Basically I wrote up a mock JSON dictionary, used JSONSerialization to turn that into data, and passed that into a parsing object of sorts. In this particular test, however, the order had to be maintained or the test would fail, and the previously described method didn't do that. So what worked for me is instead of starting with a dictionary, I start with a test JSON string and encode that into data using utf8. When it's parsed into a dictionary, the order of the JSON string is maintained in parsed dictionary.

Comment: If you provide answer with some code example that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Dictionaries are "unordered collections"**. They do not have any order at all to their key/value pairs. Period.

If you want an ordered collection, use something other than a dictionary. (an array of single-item dictionaries is one way to do it.) You can also write code that loads a dictionary's keys into a mutable array, sorts the array, then uses the sorted array of keys to fetch key/value pairs in the desired order.

You could also create your own collection type that uses strings as indexes and keeps the items in sorted order. Swift makes that straightforward, although it would be computationally expensive.

Comment: as you said "You can also write code that loads a dictionary's keys into a mutable array, sorts the array, then uses the sorted array of keys to fetch key/value pairs", Buy Zalak, here array of keys will be sorted in terms of Alphabetically, but my concern is that Dictionary index not Alphabetically ascending, descending

Comment: reported as not an answer. For example, we have server (php), android app (java) and ios app (swift). Yes, maybe it is a bad practice to use ordered dictionaries. But in the same time php and java support ordered dictionaries but swift doesn't. So according to your logic we need to rewrite 2 apps instead of one. And what do you plan to do if you don't even own this server to remove the ordered arrays from requests?

Answer (score 0):

What the question calls a "dictionary" is actually an "object" in JSON lingo.

To quote directly from the authoritative source (https://www.json.org/json-en.html):

> "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs."

So yes, treating JSON "dictionaries" as ordered is not covered by the standard.

However, I found this helpful in roundtrip-type applications: if you need to programmatically modify some value in a user-supplied JSON-file, you would generally like to maintain the overall JSON "layout". Not least, this gives you easy DIFFing capability.

As the above answers suggest, multiple JSON parsing libraries support such behaviour.

To add to the knowledge base: in Python, I have successfully used the default `json` library and found that it *does* maintain item ordering for "dictionaries"="objects". So I can do something like the following, and rest assured that I will be processing all keys in the order that they are listed in the original JSON file:

```
import json
with open(fn) as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
for regid, val in data["registers"].items():
    logging.info(f"Processing {regid} with value {val}...")
```

Corresponding sample JSON file:

```
{
   "registers": {
      "volume": 16.0,
      "brightness": 0.5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Maintain JSON object key order in swift

Once you get over everyone telling you you can't, or its wrong, or you can't rely on a JSON object's order because of the specification…etc. You can just go ahead and do the impossible as follows:

Add a dependency to [swift-collections](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections) in your `Package.swift` so we have access to `OrderedDictionary`.

Go grab a copy of `JSONSerialization+Parser.swift` from `swift-corelibs-foundation` and put it somehwere in your project.

*Using curl:*

```bash
curl -L -o "${YOUR_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/JSONSerialization+Parser.swift" 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/c284a2390b9050386758e36e4c2a2b648493efd9/Sources/Foundation/JSONSerialization%2BParser.swift'
```

*Or download manually from GitHub (Note: my patch was created against commit c284a23) :* [Permalink to JSONSerialization+Parser.swift (commit c284a23)](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blame/c284a2390b9050386758e36e4c2a2b648493efd9/Sources/Foundation/JSONSerialization%2BParser.swift)

Apply the following changes to `JSONSerialization+Parser.swift`

```
@@ -9,7 +9,8 @@
 // See https://swift.org/CONTRIBUTORS.txt for the list of Swift project authors
 //
 //===----------------------------------------------------------------------===//
-
+import OrderedCollections
+import Foundation

 internal struct JSONParser {
     var reader: DocumentReader
@@ -142,7 +143,7 @@

     // MARK: - Object parsing -

-    mutating func parseObject() throws -> [String: JSONValue] {
+    mutating func parseObject() throws -> OrderedDictionary<String, JSONValue> {
         precondition(self.reader.read() == ._openbrace)
         guard self.depth < 512 else {
             throw JSONError.tooManyNestedArraysOrDictionaries(characterIndex: self.reader.readerIndex - 1)
@@ -162,7 +163,7 @@
             break
         }

-        var object = [String: JSONValue]()
+        var object = OrderedDictionary<String, JSONValue>()
         object.reserveCapacity(20)

         while true {
@@ -663,3 +664,29 @@
     case singleFragmentFoundButNotAllowed
     case invalidUTF8Sequence(Data, characterIndex: Int)
 }
+
+enum JSONValue: Equatable {
+    case null
+    case array([JSONValue])
+    case object(OrderedDictionary<String, JSONValue>)
+    case bool(Bool)
+    case string(String)
+    case number(String)
+
+    func unwrap() throws -> Any {
+        switch self {
+        case .null: return NSNull()
+        case let .array(values): return try values.map { try $0.unwrap() }
+        case let .object(object): return try object.mapValues { try $0.unwrap() }
+        case let .bool(bool): return NSNumber(value: bool)
+        case let .string(string): return string
+        case let .number(string):
+            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
+            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
+            guard let number = formatter.number(from: string) else {
+                throw JSONError.numberIsNotRepresentableInSwift(parsed: string)
+            }
+            return number
+        }
+    }
+}
```

You can then use it like this:

```swift
import Foundation
import OrderedCollections

@main
public enum swift_json_ordered_dictionary {
    public static func main() {
        let jsonStr = """
        {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "age": 30,
            "orderMatters": "Sometimes order matters even when the world is telling you you're wrong",
            "inOrder": "Look at me ma, I've got myself in order",
            "ducksInARow": "Having all your ducks in a row",
            "favorites": {
                "color": "Rainbow",
                "food": "Pizza",
                "animal": "Unicorn",
                "activity": "Napping"
            },
            "programmingLanguages": ["Swift", "Python", "JavaScript", "Gibberish"],
            "job": "Developer",
            "quote": "Debugging is like being the detective in a crime movie where you are also the murderer",
            "nestedObjects": {
                "nested1": {
                    "message": "Order matters, even in nested objects!"
                },
                "nested2": {
                    "message": "Embrace the chaos, but keep things in order."
                },
                "nested3": {
                    "message": "Defying conventions, because order is a beautiful thing."
                }
            }
        }
        """
        do {
            var parser = JSONParser(bytes: Array(jsonStr.utf8))
            let jsonValue = try parser.parse()
            let x = try jsonValue.unwrap()
            if let dict = x as? OrderedDictionary<String, Any> {
                print(dict.prettyPrint())
            }
        } catch { print("\(error)") }
    }
}
```

**Note**: the `.prettyPrint()` function is just an extension I added to `OrderedDictionary` to give a nice output like this:

```json
{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 30,
  "orderMatters": "Sometimes order matters even when the world is telling you you're wrong",
  "inOrder": "Look at me ma, I've got myself in order",
  "ducksInARow": "Having all your ducks in a row",
  "favorites": {
    "color": "Rainbow",
    "food": "Pizza",
    "animal": "Unicorn",
    "activity": "Napping"
  },
  "programmingLanguages": [
    "Swift",
    "Python",
    "JavaScript",
    "Gibberish",
  ],
  "job": "Developer",
  "quote": "Debugging is like being the detective in a crime movie where you are also the murderer",
  "nestedObjects": {
    "nested1": {
      "message": "Order matters, even in nested objects!"
    },
    "nested2": {
      "message": "Embrace the chaos, but keep things in order."
    },
    "nested3": {
      "message": "Defying conventions, because order is a beautiful thing."
    }
  }
}
```

And as you can see, order was maintained with very minimal changes to `JSONSerialization+Parser.swift`.

Here is a little helper to apply the changes above to `JSONSerialization+Parser.swift` in a single command:

```bash
patch "${YOUR_PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/JSONSerialization+Parser.swift" < <(cat <<'EOF'
@@ -9,7 +9,8 @@
 // See https://swift.org/CONTRIBUTORS.txt for the list of Swift project authors
 //
 //===----------------------------------------------------------------------===//
-
+import OrderedCollections
+import Foundation

 internal struct JSONParser {
     var reader: DocumentReader
@@ -142,7 +143,7 @@

     // MARK: - Object parsing -

-    mutating func parseObject() throws -> [String: JSONValue] {
+    mutating func parseObject() throws -> OrderedDictionary<String, JSONValue> {
         precondition(self.reader.read() == ._openbrace)
         guard self.depth < 512 else {
             throw JSONError.tooManyNestedArraysOrDictionaries(characterIndex: self.reader.readerIndex - 1)
@@ -162,7 +163,7 @@
             break
         }

-        var object = [String: JSONValue]()
+        var object = OrderedDictionary<String, JSONValue>()
         object.reserveCapacity(20)

         while true {
@@ -663,3 +664,29 @@
     case singleFragmentFoundButNotAllowed
     case invalidUTF8Sequence(Data, characterIndex: Int)
 }
+
+enum JSONValue: Equatable {
+    case null
+    case array([JSONValue])
+    case object(OrderedDictionary<String, JSONValue>)
+    case bool(Bool)
+    case string(String)
+    case number(String)
+
+    func unwrap() throws -> Any {
+        switch self {
+        case .null: return NSNull()
+        case let .array(values): return try values.map { try $0.unwrap() }
+        case let .object(object): return try object.mapValues { try $0.unwrap() }
+        case let .bool(bool): return NSNumber(value: bool)
+        case let .string(string): return string
+        case let .number(string):
+            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
+            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
+            guard let number = formatter.number(from: string) else {
+                throw JSONError.numberIsNotRepresentableInSwift(parsed: string)
+            }
+            return number
+        }
+    }
+}

EOF
)
```

Answer (score -1):

设计思路是通过脚本**修改原始JSON，在每个项目前加上编号**。在Swift中读取JSON后，按照编号排序。

The design approach is to **modify the original JSON** through a script by **adding a number in front of each item**, and then sort the JSON in Swift according to the added number.

我们通过Python脚本来为JSON添加编号：

We use a Python script to add numbers to the JSON:

```
import json
import os
# Change the current working directory to the directory where the script is located
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Read the file
with open("RSSSourceGPT.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Create a copy
data_copy = data.copy()

# Add index in front of the keys
for i, key in enumerate(data.keys()):
    new_key = str(i) + "_" + key
    data_copy[new_key] = data_copy.pop(key)

# Save the copy
with open("RSSSourceGPT_copy.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(data_copy, f)
```

Then in Swift, we read the JSON:

```
let unsortedJSON = try JSONSerialization......//complete the code
```

Then sort the sources in their original order:

```
let sortedSources = sources.sorted(by: { (source1, source2) -> Bool in
    if let index1 = Int(source1.name.components(separatedBy: "_").first ?? ""),
       let index2 = Int(source2.name.components(separatedBy: "_").first ?? "") {
        return index1 < index2
    }
    return false
})
```

Finally, remove the index tag from each key name:

```
let sourcesWithoutIndex = sources.map { (source) -> RSSSourceGPT in
    let nameWithoutIndex = source.name.components(separatedBy: "_").count > 1 ?
        source.name.components(separatedBy: "_")[1] : source.name
    return RSSSourceGPT(id: source.id, name: nameWithoutIndex, desc: source.desc)
}
```