# Swift json decoding loses json object key order

Tags: json, swift

I have a simple JSON object:

```
{
    "values": {
        "a":"",
        "b":"",
        "c":"",
        "d":"",
        "e":""
    }
}
```

and I want to decode it to a Swift struct in such a way, **that I can later be able to iterate over the keys in `values` in the exact same order as I receive the JSON object**.

Is this possible in Swift?

---

My try below:

```
let json = "{ \"values\": { \"a\":\"\", \"b\":\"\", \"c\":\"\", \"d\":\"\", \"e\":\"\" } }"

struct JSS: Codable {
    var values: [String: String?]?
}

let data = json.data(using: .utf8)

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let jss = try decoder.decode(JSS.self, from: data!)
    jss.values?.map { print("\($0.key)") }
}
catch {
}
```

will print:

```
b
e
a
d
c
```

Comment: JSON Dictionaries are unordered by definition and so are Swift Dictionaries. According to the JSON standard, the ordering inside a Dictionary does not need to be kept when encoding/decoding the JSON, so what you are seeing is the expected behaviour.

Comment: If you need to iterate your keys alphabetically just sort your parsed dictionary by its keys. I don't think that it is possible to get the same order as it comes.

Comment: Btw you can use triple double quotes to make it easier to represent your JSON string without having to escape special characters `let json = """
{ "values": { "a":"", "b":"", "c":"", "d":"", "e":"" } }
"""`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not a Swift limitation per se. Both Swift and JSON Dictionaries are unordered. The JSON format does not guarantee key ordering, and as such, does not require parsers to preserve the order.

If you need an ordered collection, you'd be better off with returning an array of key-value pairs in the JSON:

```
{
    "values": [
        {"a" : ""},
        {"b" : ""},
        {"c" : ""},
        {"d" : ""},
        {"e" : ""}
    ]
}
```

And then store the keys in the right order to be able to iterate over them as you wish.

Comment: Good answer. (Voted.) Unfortunately many JSON parsers *do* preserve the order of key/value pairs in the list, so developers program to depend on it, even though, as you say, it is not guaranteed.

Comment: Note that when encoding the JSON encoder allows you to have the keys sorted in lexicographic order.

Comment: Here is away to do it in swift with an OrderedDictionary https://stackoverflow.com/a/76344268/2974621

Answer (score -1):

#### The following does not work **so** you don't waste time trying:

Back to the old fashion way, use `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions) -> Any`.

It does keep order..... **UNTIL** you cast `json?["values"]` into a `[String: Any]`. At this time what Cezar says in the above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48999190/1679768) enters the scene: dictionaries are unordered.

The following screenshot shows that, until `json?["values"]` is an `Any`, the order is kept in the string description.

[image: Playground demo]