# Parsing JSON in Swift 4 (Beginner coder)

Tags: json, swift, parsing, swift4

Sorry in advance if this is a stupid question. I'm really new to this.

So I'm trying to make a simple app that shows the current bitcoin price for a specific currency chosen by the user.

First I prepare the URL:

```
let baseURL = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/"
let currencyArray = ["AUD", "BRL","CAD","CNY","EUR","GBP","HKD","IDR","ILS","INR","JPY","MXN","NOK","NZD","PLN","RON","RUB","SEK","SGD","USD","ZAR"]
    var finalURL = ""

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        finalURL = baseURL + currencyArray[row]
        coinSelected = currencyArray[row]
        getBitcoinData(url: finalURL)
    }
```

Then I get the JSON data.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
            .responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.isSuccess {
                    let bitcoinJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                    print bitcoinJSON
```

So far so good, I get my JSON data and it prints correctly.

```
{
    "time": {
        "updated": "Apr 17, 2020 08:39:00 UTC",
        "updatedISO": "2020-04-17T08:39:00+00:00",
        "updateduk": "Apr 17, 2020 at 09:39 BST"
    },
    "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
    "bpi": {
        "USD": {
            "code": "USD",
            "rate": "7,074.9583",
            "description": "United States Dollar",
            "rate_float": 7074.9583
        },
        "GBP": {
            "code": "GBP",
            "rate": "5,687.3185",
            "description": "British Pound Sterling",
            "rate_float": 5687.3185
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do next is fetch the rate for GBP. (Somehow the USD rate is always displayed before the currency I pick)

What I tried to do is:

```
 func updateBitcoinData(json : JSON) {

        let bitcoinRATE = json ["bpi"][1]["rate"]
        print(bitcoinVALUE)

    }
```

But it always return nil...

Comment: `json ["bpi"]` is a Dictionary, not an Array, so doing `json ["bpi"][1]` doesn't make sense. Doing `json ["bpi"]["USD"]` or `json ["bpi"]["GBP"]` does though.

Comment: @Larme, why are you posting an answer as a comment?  Post it as an answer so it can get accepted.

Comment: But how do I just select the currency that comes after USD? I cannot just do json ["bpi"]["GBP”] because the currency is always different. That's why I tried to specify [1] to mean "pick the second value"...

Comment: You don't. It's Dictionary vs Array. Two different logic for accessing data. One is by index (ordered), the other one is by key (unordered). It's printing the USD as first, because of some unknown reason, it could change tomorrow and the data will be the same.

Comment: Order is not guaranteed in json dictionaries, you can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290866/ordered-dictionary-in-json

Comment: "But how do I just select the currency that comes after USD?" As others have said, the concept of "order" doesn't exist in dictionaries. You might want to frame the problem another way - e.g. are you trying to _get the currency that is not USD (given there are always exactly 2 currencies)_, or _get the second currency when the currencies are sorted in descending lexicographical order_? Those are problems that make sense.

Comment: Ok it's starting to make sense! @Sweeper Yes, the currency that "is not USD" would be perfect. As there are indeed only 2 currencies everytime. How do I do that?!

Comment: You can use a codable object to map JSON https://medium.com/xcblog/painless-json-parsing-with-swift-codable-2c0beaeb21c1 and help with this https://jsonmaster.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not access a dictionary with an index such as `[1]`. The elements in a dictionary have no guaranteed order. Today, the elements are ordered USD, GBP, but tomorrow, it might be GBP, USD. They are still technically the same dictionary. Therefore, you should always use the dictionary's `Key` to access it. e.g. `["GBP"]`.

From the context of the question, it seems like what you want to do is to get the user-selected currency, but the API will always give a rate for USD for reference.

In `didSelectRow`, you assigned the selected currency to `coinSelected`, so you can just use `coinSelected` as the key:

```
if let bitcoinRATE = json["bpi"][coinSelected]["rate"].string {
    // success!
} else {
    // the user has changed the selection before the response is received 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two currencies just find the `first` key which is not `USD`

```
let currencies = bitcoinJSON["bpi"]
if let notUSDCurrency = currencies.dictionary?.keys.first(where: { $0 != "USD" }) {
    let rate = currencies[notUSDCurrency]["rate"].stringValue
    print( "Rate of \(notUSDCurrency):", rate)
}
```