# Swift keep order while converting to JSON using JSONEncoder

Tags: json, swift, codable

How can I convert `Codable struct` to a JSON `Data` object and **keep the order of the struct variables**? I know that `Dictionary` is not ordered and that `JSONEncoder` and `JSONSerialization.data` accepts only `Dictionary` or `Array`. I need it to contain order only for URLRequest `httpBody`, but not when receiving data. As `httpBody` is Data object maybe I can avoid using `JSONEncoder` and convert struct straight to a Data object?

```
struct RequestBody: Codable {
    let paramB: String
    let paramC: String
    let paramA: String
}
```

Currently, the only way I figured out to do it is manually convert it to JSON string:

```
func toString() -> String {
  return """
        {"paramB":paramB,"paramC":\(paramC),"paramA":\(paramA)}
     """
 }
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42290866/ordered-dictionary-in-json JSON objects have undefined order by definition. If the order is important, your API must be changed. You could technically implement your own version of JSONEncoder but that would not be simple.

Comment: Your ideas are exactly correct. You could create a JSONEncoder from scratch, or you could just write bytes to an output stream. Your requirement violates the semantics of JSON, but you could certainly build it from scratch. This is a major undertaking, and there's no easy "here's how you do it." You're likely better off writing a custom string formatter that deals with your precise (non-standard) format requirement for your specific data types.

Comment: @Sulthan The problem is that API can't be changed and it must be done on the client-side. Now it must be some way to do it or I will have to manually make json string

Comment: Yes, you will have to manually make the "JSON-like" string.

Comment: The only option you have when encoding is `outputFormatting = .sortedKeys`

Comment: Maybe it actually would be helpful to mention that I need JSON to be ordered as a Data object while settings httpBody for URLRequest not when receiving data. @RobNapier

Comment: @kosas edit your question, post your struct and the expected output

Comment: @kosas I don't understand your clarification. What is "ordered as a Data object?" If you mean that you need to encode JSON-objects in a way that promises a key order other than "sorted by name," then you're going to have to write that JSON-like string/data by hand. The JSON format doesn't promise ordering. JSONEncoder doesn't promise ordering. And NSJSONSerialization doesn't promise ordering. So you'll need to write something else.

Comment: (BTW, not a bad question. I totally feel for you. A server developer really messed you up here by requiring something the standard doesn't promise. But the answer is the same: you're going to have to do it by hand.)

Comment: updated struct to better represent why sortedKeys doesn't work for me

Comment: Thats the easiest solution to your issue. If you don't have many structures that requires an specific order. I would just return `Data` instead of `String` and make it a computed property `var data: Data {
    .init(
"""
{"paramB":\(paramB),"paramC":\(paramC),"paramA":\(paramA)}
""".utf8)
}`

Comment: With a complex data structure, I would probably use some special keys, e.g. `KEY#01`, `KEY#02`, then use `outputFormatting = .sortedKeys` and then replace the keys as strings in the final JSON.

Comment: Your current solution is missing `"` around the values, but other than that it looks correct.

Comment: I came across this issue when base64 encoded a JSON dict for an image URL. Because the ordering wasn't guaranteed, the base64 string would change and invalidate my cache. Thanks, @LeoDabus I constructed the raw string myself as per your suggestion.