# What determines the order of returned JSON?

Tags: swift, vapor

Forgive me if this is not a Swift problem, but at this point I don't know.

My returned JSON looks like this:

```
[
   {
      "name" : _,
      "age" : _,
      "jobs" : [],
      "gender" : _
   }
]
```

But my Codable Struct looks like

```
struct Person: Codable {
   let name: String
   let age: Int
   let gender: String
   let jobs: [Job]
}
```

Is it random or I did fail to set a parameter or what?

Comment: JSON dictionaries are inherentially unordered. If you would like to learn why that is, check you would have to look into how [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) data structures work. That's the backing data structure behind Swift's `Dictionary`, and JSON's objects.

Comment: Thanks, that's very insightful, now when decoding this back into Swift, if I understand you correctly I could have the json dictionary anywhere but the objects needs to remain ordered?

Comment: @SergioBost the answer is that when you're decoding, you match the objects by name, not by position

Comment: No, the answer is that dictionaries **DO NOT HAVE ANY ORDER**. The objects might arrive in the same order every time, or they might not. Both JSON and Swift say that dictionaries are **unordered**.

Comment: But everything that is not a dictionary will be ordered as is?

Comment: @SergioBost, "everything that is not a dictionary" in JSON is an array and a value. Arrays are ordered, and a value is singular

Comment: Depends. Some frameworks let you set the field order with annotations. For example in Java Jackson the annotation @JsonPropertyOrder can be used to order the fields in json. But this is only a cosmetic thing to improve human readability (for example have more important fields first). From a programmatic point of view it makes no difference.

Comment: @nharrer Indeed, there are times when supporting ordering within JSON objects is useful, even if the JSON ends up eventually being by a system that ignores order. I ran into this once when making a program that edits JSON config files that were meant to be controlled in git. If I used typical unordered dictionaries, each key insertion might also rearrange the rest of the objects' contents, which blew up the diff. Of course, the system that consumed these files ignored the order and had it indeterminate, as is typical.

Comment: I think it would be great if @Alexander posts his comment as an answer and be marked as the answer to this question. Or else it would be stuck as an unanswered question in Stack Overflow forever.

Comment: @Alexander yes please post your comment as the answer

Comment: @SergioBost I've been in the hospital for emergency surgery lol. I'm back now, writing up an answer.

Comment: @Alexander Glad you’re better it seems

Comment: @SergioBost Indeed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON's dictionaries are unordered, as defined by the JSON spec. Even if you produced JSON that has object fields ordered a particular way, no JSON-spec compliant consumer is obligated to respect your orderinging.

Swift's `Dictioanry` is similarly unordered, and seeded differently on every app launch in order to resist hash collision based DOS attacks.

That being said, there are times when trying to manipulate JSON in an order-sensitive way can be beneficial, even if not required by the spec. Consider the example of a tool that's meant to manipulate JSON files that are version controlled in git.

Most tools work by reading a file's contents, parsing it to a data structure, manipulating the data structure, and then saving it to the file anew. Such a process would cause a small change (like adding/removing a single key) to cause a full rearranging of the entries, changes to unrelated white-space, etc., all of which would blow up the diff.

In cases like that, it's useful to use  order-sensitive parsers and collections, which preserve enough information about the original text so as to let you manipulate it in a minimal way.

Of course, the system that consumes these files would ignore the order, as is typical.

Comment: And here is a quick and easy way to do that in swift: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76344268/2974621

Answer (score 1):

You can setup json strings in lexicographic order.If you have a jsonObject, such as data, then you can convert it to json string like this:

```
let jsonString = JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data,
                                        options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.sortedKeys)
```

when you use sortedKeys option, the json will specify that the output sorts keys in lexicographic order